# How to apply highlight function on each table row?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I developed a web project where I can upload two files and django server execute a function to return the lines that don't match with other in a pandas dataframe which is renderized in a html template. Is returned a two columns table, file1 and file2. I would like to have another column with the text and text difference 'highlighted'. I have no knowledge about javascript programing, but I don't know how to apply the function on each table row.
My views.py

```
def index(request):
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            check = CheckFiles(form.cleaned_data["arquivo1"], form.cleaned_data["arquivo2"]).verifica_tamanho()
            if type(check) == str:
                return HttpResponse('The file are the same!')
            #return HttpResponse(check.to_html())
            return render(request, 'index2.html', {'check': check})
            
    else:
        print('Invalid Form!')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

and in my index2.html:

```
<table class="table" border="1px">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Original File</th>
          <th scope="col">Secondary File</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    <tr>
        {% for _, record in check.iterrows %}
            <tr>
                {% for value in record %}
                    <td>{{ value }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the highlight javascript function is:

```
highlight($("#new"), $("#old"));

function highlight(newElem, oldElem){ 
  var oldText = oldElem.text(),     
      text = '';
  newElem.text().split('').forEach(function(val, i){
    if (val != oldText.charAt(i))
      text += "<span class='highlight'>"+val+"</span>";  
    else
      text += val;            
  });
  newElem.html(text); 
}

.highlight {background-color: #B4D5FF}
```

So, I need some help to understand how to apply this javascript function on each table row.
Thank you, have a nice day.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: how to apply this function in my case? once I don't have a way to create <td id='old'>{{ value }}</td> and <td id='new'>{{ value }}</td>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you also use jquery so:

```
$(.table tr).each(function(index){
 $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

that way you can apply highlight to every row.
It seems like your current highlight function "highlights" chars that have changed in the string but I have no idea what it has to do with rows... What is $("#new") ... what is $("#old")...

**UPDATE **

```
$("table tr").each(function(index){
  a = $(this).find("td");
  first_td = a.eq(0);
  second_td = a.eq(1);
  
  highlight(second_td, first_td);
});
```

Comment: The old and new came from the original case where I get this function. I wasn't know the .each in javascript, thank you. But I don't know how to apply this, because in my case I am using: 
<tr>
                {% for value in record %}
                    <td>{{ value }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
without define id or class to td element.

Comment: what do you want to higlight ? Some specific rows or which one ? Sorry, we still dont know what is your objective. I used jquery, not pure javascript, as I can see in your code there is also jquery code.

Comment: My objective is to highlight the diff between the columns, for every row. The initial idea was to create the third column with this, but I think is much better the highlight these rows without create another column

Comment: @victorcd is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: I believe so, but I can't see what the function is returning. In this case, can I ignore my function? highlight(second_td, first_td); doesn't refer to my higilight function? I am sorry, I am going to test this when I arrive my home. Thank you.

Comment: I wrote it in mind that if refers to your function. If #new is "Second Column" and #old is "First Column" then you have access to both `td's` for every row. Your function will fire for every row.

Comment: It's awesome, thank you so much. 
In this case, need I to create the third column, like in my first idea? Could you help me how to apply this creating another column? I see no problem if the javascript function only highlight the text, without create another column.

Comment: @victorcd I think its all about learning something here. this forum is not about doing someonelse's job. I would advise you to gain some basic knowledge of javascript if you as web developer doing stuff like that, Don't get me wrong but How could I know if you need to create third column ? Peace

Comment: Thank you so much, and sorry. I was able to apply your changes and I could made this fine.